# How to get Vertex Declaration in DX9

Tags: c++, directx

In DX9, I can get IDirect3DVertexBuffer9 and Stride using "GetStreamSource" in "DrawIndexedPrimitive". And I want to get more information about Vertex. I want get Vertex Declaration (IDirect3DVertexDeclaration9) of this stream source. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you define your vertex format by [IDirect3DDevice9::CreateVertexDeclaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174365%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then you can call [IDirect3DVertexDeclaration9::GetDeclaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205920%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve your vertex declaration. if you define your vertex in the old way(the D3D_FVF format), you cannot do that.